# Highlight the working days using conditional format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

here I have a sheet in which there is a calendar and in that I need to highlight some days according to some names. If we tick on a name we need to highlight some days in that calendar. Instructions are there in the sheet and an example is also there in the Sheet 2. Please take a look.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UqQX2uXeRkLJNjaR1wfQfbrgqgnCH1eJWRI8IH4xyN4/edit#gid=0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For row 3 set the range to A3:G3 and use this custom formula

```
= (A$3<>"")*($I$3=TRUE)
```

Add a rule for every row, updating the range and the custom formula. So for row 4 the range would be A4:G4 and the custom formula

```
= (A$4<>"")*($I$4=TRUE)
```

Also see the tab 'JPV' where you see these formulas applied.
See if that works?

[image]

Comment: can u please take a look to the 'Query' tab and solve that? cz when i tried to change dates according to that tab it didn't worked. please help me

Comment: it not correct my friend 13 to 22 means it must include 13,154,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 while tick HARRY